# Animating Image Object Opacity in Canvas Using GreenSock's TweenLite

Tags: javascript, canvas, opacity, alpha, gsap

I'm currently building an animated banner using Canvas. I've got coloured SVG dot graphics set as Image() objects on my canvas. I've been animating the dots on the canvas along x,y paths and I'd like the dots to fade out by the end of their animations...

I can't seem to figure out how to animate opacity values in canvas using TweenLite... In fact, I'm not even sure how to animate opacity on the dots at all, even through plain JavaScript.. I haven't been able to find any answers on Google.. Does anyone here know how to achieve this desired effect? (preferably using TweenLite)

For context sake, here is a small snippet of the code I'm currently working with:

```
function drawDot()
            {
                ctx.drawImage(orDt, orDtObj.x, orDtObj.y); //draw an orange dot in the canvas
            }
            function reAnimateDot() //set dot back to it's origin
            {
                orDtObj.x = xDotOgn; 
                orDtObj.y = yDotOgn; 

                animateDot();
            }

            function animateDot()
            { 
                var angle = Math.random()*(Math.PI*2);

                console.log('>> the angle : '+angle)

                var radius = 100;

                //find the end point for our dot
                var xEnd = orDtObj.x + radius * Math.cos( angle );
                var yEnd = orDtObj.y + radius * Math.sin( angle ) ;

                orDtObj.xEnd = xEnd;
                orDtObj.yEnd = yEnd;

                TweenLite.to(orDtObj, 2, {x:orDtObj.xEnd,  y:orDtObj.yEnd, autoAlpha:0, ease:Quad.easeOut, onUpdate:reDrawUnit, onComplete:reAnimateDot});
            }
```

Comment: Instead of `autoAlpha: 0`, have you tried `opacity: 0` or even `alpha: 0`?

Comment: Possible for you to create a small jsFiddle demonstrating this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One way I was able to achieve this effect, is by layering canvas objects overtop each other much like layers in Flash. I basically grouped elements together that I wanted to fade in and out on their own canvas objects, and then tweened the actual canvas globalAlpha property on each canvas separately.. seemed to do the trick..

Please comment if you guys know of any other way that might work..